# Select distinct column A where column B contains all required data?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table for an attendance system(IN/OUT), here's a sample data.

```
ID |            Date         | Transaction
 1 | 2016-03-21 06:04:55.000 |     I
 2 | 2016-03-21 06:04:55.000 |     I
 3 | 2016-03-21 06:04:55.000 |     I
 4 | 2016-03-21 06:04:55.000 |     I
 1 | 2016-03-21 17:04:55.000 |     O
 2 | 2016-03-21 17:04:55.000 |     O
 3 | 2016-03-21 17:04:55.000 |     O
 1 | 2016-03-22 06:04:55.000 |     I
 2 | 2016-03-22 06:04:55.000 |     I
 3 | 2016-03-22 06:04:55.000 |     I
 4 | 2016-03-22 06:04:55.000 |     I
 1 | 2016-03-22 17:04:55.000 |     O
 2 | 2016-03-22 17:04:55.000 |     O
 3 | 2016-03-22 17:04:55.000 |     O
 4 | 2016-03-22 17:04:55.000 |     O
 ...........
```

What I want to get is all ID's that has an IN and OUT transaction for every date I give, so in my example if I give March 21 and 22 I will get ID's 1-3 only since 4 doesn't have an OUT transaction on March 21. I tried using an IN statement but doesn't work since it retrieves all IDs that have a transaction in any date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT ID
FROM mytable
WHERE CAST([Date] AS Date) IN ('2016-03-21', '2016-03-22')
GROUP BY ID
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT CASE 
                        WHEN CAST([Date] AS Date) = '2016-03-21' THEN Transaction 
                      END) = 2 
       AND
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE 
                        WHEN CAST([Date] AS Date) = '2016-03-22' THEN Transaction 
                      END) = 2
```